# Can Relay and Redux work together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, relayjs

And if they can what are the ways to integrate them? Some (anti)patterns?

I have invested some time in learning both of them but still can't figure out the way to leverage both of them (with their strong points) in a single application.

Comment: not well suited question for stack, but I'm sure a lot of your questions are answered here already https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/464

Comment: These two discussions are worth reading:
1) [Relay and Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/464)
2) [Has Redux's Time Come and Gone](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/775)
. In a nutshell, their scopes are different. So, ideally they should not be used together.

Comment: @AhmadFerdous
If their scopes are different, doesn't it mean you should use them together? (Redux for local states and Relay for server states, as Relay won't be able to handle locale state like a "loading" state to display an app spinner) Here's an article that may help http://beautifulcode.1stdibs.com/2016/09/07/reconcile-relay-redux/

Comment: [this article](http://beautifulcode.1stdibs.com/2016/09/07/reconcile-relay-redux/) offers a nesting (relay>redux>react) solution